# Error in Electron | Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, webtorrent

I'm trying to download a torrent with Electron and Node.js using [WebTorrent](http://webtorrent.io). Well, this is my code in main.js

```
const electron = require('electron')
const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron

const path = require('path')
const url  = require('url')
const server = require('./server')

let win

function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow ({ vibrancy: 'dark', width: 400, height: 600, frame: false, resizable: false, transparent: true })
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'file',
    slashes: true
  }))
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

And my code in server.js is:

```
require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
  var WebTorrent = require('webtorrent-hybrid')

  var client = new WebTorrent()

  var magnetURI = 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:EF3B95AEF1C94FC8E98825386C3B12560FE21CFF&amp;tr=udp://glotorrents.pw:6969/announce&amp;tr=udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce&amp;tr=udp://torrent.gresille.org:80/announce&amp;tr=udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80&amp;tr=udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969&amp;tr=udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969&amp;tr=udp://p4p.arenabg.ch:1337&amp;tr=udp://tracker.internetwarriors.net:1337'

  client.add(magnetURI, { path: 'movies' }, function (torrent) {
    torrent.on('done', function () {
      console.log('torrent download finished')
    })
  })

  res.end('Hello from server started by Electron app!');

}).listen(9000)
```

The problem starts when I run the app and appears this message on the console:

**(node:9032) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 ready listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit**

Answer (score 0):

Its just a warning!!!

As per the Nodejs.org documentation

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n

By default EventEmitters will print a warning if more than 10 listeners are added for a particular event. This is a useful default that helps finding memory leaks. Obviously, not all events should be limited to just 10 listeners. The emitter.setMaxListeners() method allows the limit to be modified for this specific EventEmitter instance. The value can be set to Infinity (or 0) to indicate an unlimited number of listeners.

So you need to add a below line in your code

"emitter.setMaxListeners(n)"

Comment: In main.js or server.js?

Comment: Can you show me the trace? so that I can tell exactly where to put this line.

Comment: Also, if you actually do have an emitter memory leak (rather than just happening to need 11 listeners and no more), then you need to fix that problem at its source - raising the limit won't help you. Just a note.

Comment: I am not getting the warning. Can you mention the specs of computer, OS and Node version.

Comment: Windows 10
Node version: v8.9.4

Comment: And the index.html file has this <a> tag:
    <a href="http://localhost:9000">
The warning shows when I click the <a> tag. Or, when I enter to localhost:9000 in my browser.

Comment: Whats the config of you machine? Ram?

Comment: I have 8gb of ram

Comment: https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent/issues/479#issuecomment-158780856 As per the issue mentioned here, you need to switch to the streaming library for downloading the files from torrent. There is an npm package available torrent-stream.